# How do I throw an exception if an element is present that shouldn't be

Tags: c#

I am using XmlReader.  I am basically going through an if statement reading each element if it's present.  If I come across an element that shouldn't be there I want to throw an XmlException.  Then I have an else basically saying if we have already read all of the elements and there aren't any that don't match what we are looking for close the element that all of these other elements are wrapped inside of.  Everthing is working except for the checking for an invalid or unrecognized element.

```
public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            if (reader.IsStartElement("job"))
            {
                //
                // Get the values of all the <job> attributes
                //
                JobName = reader.GetAttribute("name");
                MethodName = reader.GetAttribute("method");

                //
                // Read past <job>
                //
                reader.Read();

                //
                // We could have (in any order):
                //   <Description></Description>
                //   <Source></Source>
                //   <Properties></Properties>
                //   <Elements></Elements>
                // 
                while (true)
                {
                    if (reader.IsStartElement("description"))
                    {
                        Description = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    }
                    else if (reader.IsStartElement("source"))
                    {
                        Source = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    }
                    else if (reader.IsStartElement("properties"))
                    {
                        Properties.ReadXml(reader);
                    }
                    else if ((reader.IsStartElement("elements")) && (!reader.IsEmptyElement))
                    {
                        Elements.ReadXml(reader);
                    }
                    else if ((reader.IsStartElement("parameters")) && (!reader.IsEmptyElement))
                    {
                        Parameters.ReadXml(reader);
                    }
                    else if (((!reader.IsStartElement("description"))
                        && (!reader.IsStartElement("source"))
                        && (!reader.IsStartElement("properties"))
                        && (!reader.IsStartElement("elements"))
                        && (!reader.IsStartElement("parameters"))
                        && (!reader.IsStartElement("job"))))
                    {
                        throw new XmlException("Unexpected element was present");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        reader.MoveToContent();
                        reader.ReadEndElement();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new XmlException("Expected <job> element was not present");
            }
        }
```

The part that is breaking is this code below.  It goes inside of this if statement everytime and throws and exception.

```
else if (((!reader.IsStartElement("description"))
     && (!reader.IsStartElement("source"))
     && (!reader.IsStartElement("properties"))
     && (!reader.IsStartElement("elements"))
     && (!reader.IsStartElement("parameters"))
     && (!readerE("job"))))
{
    throw new XmlException("Unexpected element was present");
}
```

Comment: What is `readerE`?

Comment: Don't throw system defined exceptions (*there are a few exceptions to that rule, no pun intended, like `ArgumentException`*), its not good practice. Instead create a new Exception type with some name like `DuplicateElementFoundException` or `InvalidElementException` and throw that.

Comment: Oops didn't realize that was still there sorry.  So basically, since all of this is wrapped in an element called <job> after it reads the other elements (description, source...etc.), reader is the ending <job> element.  I thought I could try (!readerIsEndElement("job") but xmlReader does not contain IsEndElement.

Comment: MSDN says that [`IsStartElement(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xws1azba(v=vs.110).aspx) "Calls MoveToContent and tests if ...", so every time you call it I'm pretty sure your "current position" is moving. You appear to only want to move when you get to the `else` when you call it explicitly: `reader.MoveToContent();`, but, you are also calling `MoveToContent` with every `IsStartElement` call.

Comment: Right.  But that shouldn't have an effect on me checking for an element that doesn't match any of the suggested StartElements right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that XmlReader reader contains a method for IsName(string).  It is static.  So since I could add IsEndElement to the condition because XmlReader doesn't contain this method, I was able to add XmlReader.IsName("job") to bypass the ending job element tag.

```
else if (((!reader.IsStartElement("description"))
                        && (!reader.IsStartElement("source"))
                        && (!reader.IsStartElement("properties"))
                        && (!reader.IsStartElement("elements"))
                        && (!reader.IsStartElement("parameters"))
                        && (!XmlReader.IsName("job"))))
                    {
                        throw new XmlException("Unexpected element was present");
                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The ideal way of doing this is to validate the XML against an XSD (XML schema) as provided by the System.Xml.Schema namespace. Further info and examples can be found on the applicable MSDN pages [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693087.aspx)

Example from MSDN :

```
XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add("", "CustomersOrders.xsd");

Console.WriteLine("Attempting to validate");
XDocument custOrdDoc = XDocument.Load("CustomersOrders.xml");
bool errors = false;
custOrdDoc.Validate(schemas, (o, e) =>
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.Message);
                     errors = true;
                 });
Console.WriteLine("custOrdDoc {0}", errors ? "did not validate" : "validated");
```

Comment: As I mentioned to Rich below, unfortunately I am not able to create a schema for validation.  I have to keep it the way it is.  I just need to figure out how to hit the else if that throws an exception if there is an element that does not match any of the other startElements.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably worth pointing out that the recommended practice when validating xml is to use a schema.

See the following : [XML Schema (XSD) Validation with XmlSchemaSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3740e0b5(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the good info Rich.  I have noted for next time. But unfortunately for now I have to keep it the way it is.

Comment: It's a better approach to achieving his objective of validating the xml, so I thought it worthy.